# How much does transactions for all write operations increase data consistency?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I use gorm for ORM with PostgresSQL and I noticed this in it's documentation

> GORM perform write (create/update/delete) operations run inside a transaction to ensure data consistency, you can disable it during initialization if it is not required, you will gain about 30%+ performance improvement after that

https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html

Consistency is important for my use case but I'm wondering if this is really necessary, and worth the performance hit

Comment: What are the consequences of data loss in your application? Will people die or lose money? Will they even notice? There's a *huge* spectrum here between catastrophic consequences and absolutely no issues. 30% is a pretty modest gain considering you're throwing away a lot of safety considerations, so I'd stick with transactions until you have a *measurable* performance problem.

Comment: Is this "best practice" when you want to guarantee consistency? Maybe I'm ignorant but I haven't seen this been done anywhere else or in other ORMs

Comment: ActiveRecord, Sequel, Sequelize, Eloquent, and many others all use transactions to ensure consistency when creating a record that may have dependent records that need to be created at the same time. Transactions do carry some overhead, but unless your database machine is crumbling under the load, don't worry about it. If it is overloaded and you *suspect* transactions, it's worth engage a DBA to properly research the issue. Most of the time it's not transactions, but sub-optimal configuration or server tuning issues.

Comment: You can't do anything in Postgres without a transaction. So even if don't explicitly use them, the  DML statements are always part of a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

There is a saying: you can make it arbitrarily fast, if you don't have to do it correctly. What good are broken data?

But in this case, I have to doubt the claim. In an ACID compliant relational database, you *always* pay the price for transactional processing.

By default, every statement in PostgreSQL runs in its own transaction. So if you start an explicit transaction that spans several data modifying statements, you actually *gain* performance, since you don't have to pay the price for a commit as often.

The only consideration is the network latency you incur four times when sending `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;`. But [if you have high network latency, you can say goodbye to OLTP performance anyway](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-network-latency-does-make-a-big-difference/).

Comment: "So if you start an explicit transaction that spans several data modifying statements, you actually gain performance". Is the price not 'too high' if you're just modifying a single data? Is there benefit in this case

Comment: You wouldn't start an explicit transaction if it consists of only a single statement. But apart from the cost of the extra client-server round trips, the price on the database server is minimal.